# R plot: Displaying both point type and line type in legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have generated a plot with `plot` function. I added the point markers with `pch()` and the line type with `lty`. In  the legend section I wanted to merge the points and  lines together. I used `merge=TRUE` but it didn't work. It is displaying the line type only. The same thing with `merge=FALSE`. In both cases there is only slight change in the box legend box width. That is it. Any idea?

Here is the sample code:

```
m<-1:10
n<-runif(1:5)

plot(m,type = "o", col="blue",main = "plot",xlab = "distance",ylab = "height")
lines(n+2,type="o", pch=22,lty=6,col="red")
lines(m-3,type="o", pch=17,lty=5,col="forestgreen")

legend(x=2,y=8,c("R","S","T"),lty=c(1,6,5),pch=c(5,22,17),
       cex=.8, col=c("blue","red","forestgreen"),merge = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

People have asked you to put in some toy code. This is important as it gives people a starting point to help you. Actually it is not difficult to do this. Consider the following:

```
set.seed(0); x1 <- rnorm(10); x2 <- rnorm(10); x3 <- rnorm(10)
plot(x1, type = "b", pch = 19, lty = 1, col = 1,
     ylim = range(c(x1,x2,x3)))  ## both points and lines
points(x2, pch = 19, col = 2)  ## only points
lines(x3, lty = 2, col = 3)  ## only lines
legend(6, 0.9*max(c(x1,x2,x3)), legend = c("x1", "x2", "x3"),
       pch = c(19, 19, NA), lty = c(1, NA, 2),
       col = c(1,2,3), text.col = c(1,2,3))
```

[image: test]

Use `NA` to control what you want to display.

---

**Follow-up**

> I forgot to include the `pch` in the `legend()`. When I included that the point are displaying at the right tip of each line in the legend. Is there some way of centring them?

Great! Now you have included your code in your question. The problem is with your final call to `legend()`. Do not use/set argument `merge`:

```
legend(x=2,y=8,c("R","S","T"),lty=c(1,6,5),pch=c(5,22,17),
       cex=.8, col=c("blue","red","forestgreen"))
```

This will do what you want.